# How to "resolve" library in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015

I'm doing this tutorial: http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-1/.

As a part of this I started with this tutorial to get tabbed activity in my Android project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8OURJQOcoM&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=11.

My question is I'm stucked at "Resolve" or import library into the project. Does anybody know how to do this so I'll get "using Android.Support.....;"?

Any help is appreciated!

Please see here below for the code. It is concerning the ViewPage part.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;



namespace Vorbi
{
    public class SlidingTabScrollView : HorizontalScrollView
    {

        private const int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
        private const int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
        private const int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

        private int mTitleOffset;

        private int mTabViewLayoutID;
        private int mTabViewTextViewID;

        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

        private static SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

        private int mScrollState;

        public interface TabColorizer
        {
            int GetIndicatorColor(int position);
            int GetDividerColor(int position);
        }

        public SlidingTabScrollView(Context context) : this(content, null) { }

        public SlidingTabScrollView(Context context), IAttributeSet attrs): this(context, attrs, 0) { }

        public SlidingTabScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle) : base(context, attrs, defaultStyle)
        {
            // Disable scroll bar 
            HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;

            // Make sure the tab strips fill the view
            FillViewport = true;
            this.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(0xe5, 0x5, 0x5)); // Gray color

            mTitleOffset = (int)(TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);

            mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
            this.AddView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);    
        }

        public TabColorizer CustomTabColorizer
        {
            set { mTabStrip.CustomTabColorizer = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of including links to other sites, please include the specific code that is causing a problem for you. As it currently stands, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Xamarin Component Store should be your primary source.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how do I do that if I may ask?